# Specifying Conditions on Multiple Nested Eager Loaded Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

I'm trying to query on ActiveRecord multiple nested eager loaded associations with conditions like so:

```
user.books.includes(slot: [room: :school]).where("books.slot.room.school.id = 1")
```

Obviously this query is wrong, but basically what I'm trying to reach is a relation of user.books for a certain school.

My model structure is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  has_many :slots, through: :books
  has_many :rooms, through: :slots
  has_many :schools
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :slot
end

class Slot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  belongs_to :room
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :slots
end

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :rooms
  has_many :slots, through: :rooms
  has_many :books, through: :slots
end
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`includes` eager loads association records, while `joins` does what you want to do.

This question has been asked here numerous times. Please make sure that you look and try to find a similar question here before you ask one.

So you want to change your code like this:

`user.books.joins(slot: [room: :school]).where(schools: { id: 1 })`

Comment: Hi Kkulikovskis, sorry for the delay, but it didn't actually worked as I get the next error: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table... what it does worked for me is: u.books.joins(slot: [room: :school]).where(schools: {id: 1}). Does it make sense to you?

Comment: yes, sorry. My answer did not make full sense since if you join several tables, then you can access them directly in `where`. I have updated my answer